# Find files in any subdirectory (glob)

Tags: azure-devops, glob, azure-pipelines

I was under the impression that `**` meant: any subdirectory at any depth, however, when I try it, it seems to only yield results from level 1 subdirectories:

```
$ find app | grep spec.ts
app/common/price.pipe.spec.ts
app/common/product/service/servicecontainer.spec.ts
app/common/product/service/servicefactory.spec.ts

$ find app/**/*.spec.ts
app/common/price.pipe.spec.ts
```

Why does the 2nd command not yield all 3 spec files?

Edit: I just realised enabling globstar fixes the issue, however, I'm unable to do this on a VSTS agent. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you use it in VSTS? What's the build task and how did you config?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT It's an npm command that does `npm test`. Its definition is: `mocha -r ./testhook.ts app/**/*.spec.ts`. However, it runs only the price test, not the other two.

Comment: What if you execute `npm test` command manually in your local machine?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT then it works fine

Comment: Can you provide the detail VSTS build log by setting `system.debug` as `true`?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT https://gist.github.com/Burgov/576a13feea32ccdcac573b71c7e2aa0d

Comment: For windows, just add --recursive option for mocha can solve the problem. Not sure if it's workd for linux. So what if you use `"test": "mocha -r ./testhook.ts app/*.spec.ts --recursive"` or `"test": "mocha -r ./testhook.ts './app/**/*.spec.ts'"` in your package.json file?

Answer (score -1):

> /app/* VS /app/**

/app/* is saying every file directly in the /app directory.

/app/** is saying every file in any directory inside /app directory.

**Please try this way:**

```
find app | grep -i .spec.ts
```

or

```
find app | grep .spec.ts
```

**RESULT:**

```
➜  Desktop find app | grep .spec.ts

app/common/price.pipe.spec.ts
app/common/product/service/servicefactory.spec.ts
app/common/product/service/servicecontainer.spec.ts
```

**EDIT:**

I did try your command with your folders and that's worked for me:

```
➜  Desktop find app/**/*.spec.ts
app/common/price.pipe.spec.ts
app/common/product/service/servicecontainer.spec.ts
app/common/product/service/servicefactory.spec.ts
```

Comment: your original answer doesn't mention anything explicitely about the double-star glob ( ** ) - the question is only about **